# .bashrc path problems

Tags: bash, path

Can anyone tell me how to add a directory, say `Idl`, which contains many sub-directories to my `IDL_PATH` in `.bashrc` such that when I do `source .bashrc`, I will be able to it is able to run all the executables inside all the different sub-directories?

Is this possible? I am doing

```
IDL_PATH=.:+/idl/idl70/lib:/home/cs/Idl ....
```

The `Idl` folder has many sub-directories (eg. `xidl`, `idl_code`, `net` etc.). However, I am only able to run files in folder `Idl`, not those in sub-directories.

The files which I want to run are IDL procedures with `.pro` extensions. If I put my all `.pro` files into a single directory, say `/home/cs/Idl`, then my whole pro files are being run.

Is there any way?

Comment: Do you need to add the directories to `IDL_PATH` or `PATH`?

Comment: Any thing either PATH or IDL_PATH its just a name to direct a particular path.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like `IDL_PATH` is a completely different thing and used by the idl library. Directories in your `PATH` are searched recursively, so subdirectories are added automatically. It looks like `IDL_PATH` doesn't work that way. What are you trying to do? Do you just want to be able to run programs in the `Idl` directory? If so, add `Idl` to `PATH` not `IDL_PATH`.

Comment: No it is not running even with simple PATH option. I think it should be IDL_PATH.

Comment: I want all the programs which are in various sub directories inside the main Idl directory to be run globally any where in the system.

Comment: Yes, I see now. And I was wrong, directories in `PATH` are not searched recursively. Strange, I could have sworn they were.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you will have to either add each directory that contains an executable separately or link all executables to the same directory.

1. **Add all directories manually.**

   First, collect the list of relevant directories (I am assuming you are running Linux or, in any case, that you have GNU tools):

   ```
   find /home/cs/Id -type f -executable -exec dirname {} + | sort -u
   ```

   The above will find all executable files in `/home/cs/Id` and print the name of the directory containing them. The `sort -u` ensures that each directory is only printed once. I created a few test directories, so on my system I get:

   ```
   $ find /home/terdon/Idl/ -type f -executable -exec dirname {} + | sort -u
   /home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/bag/ho
   /home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/bag/ho/fa/fe/re
   /home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/baz/foo/bar
   /home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/baz/foo/bar/baz/foo/bar/baz
   ```

   Now, you want to get these into the right format for adding to `$PATH`:

   ```
   $ find /home/terdon/Idl/ -type f -executable -exec dirname {} + | sort -u | tr '\n' ':'
   /home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/bag/ho:/home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/bag/ho/fa/fe/re:/home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/baz/foo/bar:/home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/baz/foo/bar/baz/foo/bar/baz:
   ```

   Copy that (excluding the final `:`) and add it to your `PATH`:

   ```
   PATH="$PATH:/home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/bag/ho:/home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/bag/ho/fa/fe/re:/home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/baz/foo/bar:/home/terdon/Idl/foo/bar/baz/foo/bar/baz/foo/bar/baz"
   ```
2. **Find all executable files and symlink them to a directory already in your PATH**.

   ```
   find /home/terdon/Idl/ -type f -executable -exec ln -s {} ~/bin \;
   ```

   On some Linux systems (Ubuntu, for example) the `~/bin` directory is automatically added to your `PATH` if it exists. If this doesn't happen on your system, add it yourself:

   ```
   PATH="$PATH:/home/cs/bin"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think one has to enumerate the directories, then. This generates the line for you automatically:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Copyright © 2016 Martin Ueding <dev@martin-ueding.de>
# Licensed under the MIT license

import argparse
import os


def main():
    options = _parse_args()

    additions = []

    for base in options.base:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(base):
            additions.append(dirpath)

    line = ':'.join(additions)

    if options.short:
        print(line)
    else:
        print('PATH=$PATH:'+line)


def _parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
    parser.add_argument('base', nargs='+', help='Basepath')
    parser.add_argument('--short', action='store_true')
    options = parser.parse_args()

    return options


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Save that snippet as `/usr/bin/path-recurse` and apply `chmod +x /usr/bin/path-recurse`. Then you can use it in your prompt either to generate the line with `path-recurse /tmp /foobar …` and it will give you the Bash line:

```
PATH=$PATH:/tmp:/tmp/kde-muIusrrC:/tmp/vs0cOIg:/tmp/.esd-1000:/tmp/ssh-oGWOvuUnyqPF:/tmp/.Test-unix:/tmp/.font-unix:/tmp/.XIM-unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

Alternatively you can use the following in your `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$(path-recurve /tmp /foobar …)
```

This will then dynamically go through all the folders whenever the `.bashrc` is sourced.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved my problem. All I did in my .bashrc file I wrote:

PATH=${PATH}:$(find ~/Idl -type d | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:$//')

Then: > source .bashrc

Now I am able to run all programs and scripts inside various sub-directories under my main Idl directory.

Thanks all for your kind attentions.