# Unable to modify PATH using bashrc

Tags: bash, path

I have read many posts and help files about updating the `PATH` using `.bashrc`. I might have to use `.bashrc_profile` as discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271046/bashrc-path-problems).

However, I can't get `.bashrc` to even work from the command line.

I start with

```
env | grep "$PATH"
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

In `.bashrc` is

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Permissions of `.bashrc` is `-rwxrw-r--  .bashrc`

Execute `.bashrc`, path does not change.

```
~$  env | grep "$PATH"
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
~$ ./.bashrc
~$  env | grep "$PATH"
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

Entering directly on the command line works.

```
~$ export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
~$  env | grep "$PATH"
PATH=/home/ksmith/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

What am I doing wrong? [My 'Nix is Ubuntu]

Once I can prove that .bashrc updates `PATH`, I will rename it to `.bashrc_profile` to test that `PATH` is updated when logging on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Comment: Not a duplicate of  'How to correctly add a path to PATH?'. it is a lower level problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ~$ ./.bashrc
> ```

This is the problem. If you run `.bashrc` as a program, it gets its own copy of the environment, and any changes it makes are not propagated back to the shell. You need to invoke `.bashrc` by "sourcing" it instead:

```
source ./.bashrc
```

Or, for short:

```
. ./.bashrc
```